# LINQ Subquery after .Take(1)

Tags: c#, linq

I have a LINQ query where I select a parent element that has a `where` and `orderby` clause, I need only the first result of this so I apply a `.Take(1)` to it. Then I need to select two separate children nodes from the parent that each have "where" clauses.

I have successfully done this using two distinct LINQ queries but I feel like it should only need one query with a subquery in it, the part that is hanging me up is the `.Take(1)` on the parent,  the subquery cant continue after that call without error.

Here is what I have now, is it possible to combine these into one query?

```
var parent= 
    (from parentXML in myDal.GetMyXML().Elements("parentElements")
     where DateTime.Parse((string)parentXML.Attribute("startDate")) <= currentDate
     orderby DateTime.Parse((string)parentXML.Attribute("startDate")) descending 
     select parentXML).Take(1);
```

and:

```
var children = 
    (from firstChild in parent.Elements("childElements")
     where (string)firstChild.Attribute("type") == "first"
     from secondChild in parent.Elements("childElements")
     where (string)secondChild.Attribute("type") == "second"
     select new { first = firstChild , second = secondChild }).ToList();
```

Comment: what error do you get and can you post a sample xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick attempt:

```
var children = 
    (from parentXML in myDal.GetMyXML().Elements("parentElements")
 where DateTime.Parse((string)parentXML.Attribute("startDate")) <= currentDate
 orderby DateTime.Parse((string)parentXML.Attribute("startDate")) descending 
 select parentXML).Select(p=>new {
   first=p.Elements("childElements").Where(f=>f.Attribute("type")=="first"),
   second=p.Elements("childElements").Where(f=>f.Attribute("type")=="second")})
.Take(1);
```

Rewritten:

```
var children = 
  myDal.GetMyXML()
    .Elements("parentElements")
    .Where(p=>DateTime.Parse((string)p.Attribute("startDate"))<=currentDate)
    .OrderByDescending(p=>DateTime.Parse((string)p.Attribute("startDate")))
    .Select(p=>new {
       first=p.Elements("childElements").Where(f=>f.Attribute("type")=="first"),
       second=p.Elements("childElements").Where(f=>f.Attribute("type")=="second")})
    .Take(1);
```

Comment: This seems to be close (and very clean) but I'm getting the error "XElement does not contain a definition for Where and no extension accepting a first argument of type XElement" on the p.Where()

Comment: I've rewritten it using the method/lambda/fluent syntax completely as this is how I typically write my queries rather than a mix of the two.